# Terminal screen drawing protection mode not fully implemented in xtermjs

Tags: xtermjs

Protected fields are normally protected from DESCSED erasure to support behaviour like clearing input data or updating areas without having to redraw the whole screen (maybe a throwback to 75 baud accousticly coupled modems).

Xtermjs InputHandler.ts currentlly says "Protection attributes are not supported".

The behaviour is that on an xtermjs session that prints protected and non-protected fields, DECSED will erase the whole screen, including the protected fields.

Is full support for DECSED,DECSEL,DECSCA, etc on the roadmap for xtermjs?

Comment: why don't you ask on the github repo?

Comment: Thanks @Rainb , In the repo/Issues it redirects questions to Stack Overflow.

Comment: Maybe link this question here in the repo